# GET request from PHP to React

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, get

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

    $select_user = "SELECT * FROM users";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $row['name']."".$row['email'];
    }
 ?>
```

I'm using the above code block to retrieve details from the database in my backend & it will give relevant details. In my frontend,

```
import React, {Component}from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Row, Table, Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      userList: []
    }

    this.displayTableRows = this.displayTableRows.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var url = "http://localhost:80/PHP_REACT/backend/UserList.php";

    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => { 
          console.log(res.data); // PRINT RESULT (NEED SEPARATE RECODS ROW BY ROW)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Link to={'/Signin'}>
              <Button variant="dark" className="mt-3">
                Logout
              </Button>
            </Link>
            <Table className="mt-4 table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
            </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using this code block to getting data from the backend. It worked, but it sends all the details as one String. I need to get database records one by one & print them inside a table. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please post your code instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return data in json format from php file

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

    $select_user = "SELECT * FROM users";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    
    $data = array()
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       array_push($data,$row['name']."".$row['email']); // push data to empty array
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Comment: This works pretty much.. Also asking for a quick favour @RobinSingh.. I need to get two columns from the database(name, email) and pass it to the front end & display it. Any clue of how to get two columns separately & pass them to the front?

Comment: @prabathshalitha Just create a array inside while loop and push it. `array_push($data, array('your_column' => $your_value, 'your_second_column' => $your_second_value));`